# Print all the combinations of all the elements of two arrays (of strings)

Tags: c++

How can I print all the possible combinations of the elements of two arrays, both of them with strings?
Input: {"Tom", "John", "Alex"}
       {"Leo", "Mary"}
Output: Tom - Leo, John- Leo
        Alex- Mary, John - Mary 
        Alex- Leo, Tom - Mary

Comment: Is there anything you've tried ? Even in pseudo code

Comment: Please post what have you tried and post example arrays and what output you want.

Comment: You need two `std::vector<std::string>` and two loops. What part do you have trouble with? If you have any code please include it in the question. Currently it is not clear what problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Just iterate over both arrays and print both results like that:

```cpp
// you might want to pick a different size other than 10
std::array<std::string, 10> array1;
std::array<std::string, 10> array2;

// ... fill contents of arrays

// Iterate over both arrays and print each string combination
for (const auto& string1 : array1) {
    for (const auto& string2 : array2) {
        std::cout << string1 << ' ' << string2 << '\n';
    }
}
```

Arrays can also be declared like that:

```cpp
std::array<std::string, 3> array1 {"Tom", "John", "Alex"};
```

Comment: If the arrays have to be of dynamic size, you might want to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead just like user463035818 suggested in a comment to your question...